# content not allowed as child of element body html error

Tags: html

When validating the below html I receive the following error message

Error: Element content not allowed as child of element body in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)
From line 41, column 1; to line 41, column 9
↩↩    <
Content model for element body:
Flow content.

Could someone clarify what this means and how to remove this error?? Thank you :-)

```html
<body>

<header>
    <div class="header-wrapper">
        <div class="header-bg"></div>
        <div class="header-content">
            <ul>
                <li class="instagram">
                    <a href="" class="navBarLinks find">Find me on</a>
                    <a href="" class="navBarLinks in">
                        <svg class="insticon" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 155.2 144" style="enable-background:new 0 0 155.2 144;" xml:space="preserve">
                            <style type="text/css">
                                .st0 {}
                            </style>
                            <path class="st0" d="M50.1,121.7H28.8V53h21.4V121.7z M39.4,43.6c-6.8,0-12.4-5.6-12.4-12.4s5.5-12.4,12.4-12.4
 c6.8,0,12.4,5.5,12.4,12.4C51.8,38,46.3,43.6,39.4,43.6z M130.1,121.7h-21.3V88.3c0-8-0.1-18.2-11.1-18.2
 c-11.1,0-12.8,8.7-12.8,17.6v34H63.5V53H84v9.4h0.3c2.8-5.4,9.8-11.1,20.2-11.1c21.6,0,25.6,14.2,25.6,32.7
 C130.1,84,130.1,121.7,130.1,121.7z" />
                        </svg>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="home"><a href="" class="navBarLinks">Logo </a>
                </li>
                <li class="hamburger">
                    <a href="" id="toggle-menu" class="navBarLinks">
                        <span id="top" class="burger"></span>
                        <span id="middle" class="burger"></span>
                        <span id="bottom" class="burger"></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<content>
    <div class="stage stage-0">
        <div id="overlay">Overlay Placeholder! </div>
        <div id="arrow">
            <span class="arrow-bounce"><svg fill="#FFFFFF" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" xmlns= "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <path d="M7.41 7.84L12 12.42l4.59-4.58L18 9.25l-6 6-6-6z"/>
 <path d="M0-.75h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
 </svg>
    </span>
        </div>
        <video class="media-player" loop autoplay src="http://ak9.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/6236564/preview/stock-footage-cybernetic-brain-zooming-through-eye.mp4" style="width: 100%;height: 100%;object-fit: cover;"
>
        </video>
    </div>
    <div class="stage stage-2">3</div>
    <div class="stage stage-4">5</div>
    <div class="stage stage-6">7</div>
    <div class="stage stage-8">9</div>
    <div class="stage stage-10">11</div>
    <div class="stage stage-12">13</div>
    <div class="stage stage-14">15</div>
    <div class="stage stage-16">17</div>
    <div class="stage stage-18">19</div>
    <div class="stage stage-20">21</div>
    <div class="stage stage-22">23</div>
</content>

</body>
```

Comment: What were you using to validate your CSS? This seems more like an error that came up while validating HTML...

Comment: Please see my updates. https://validator.w3.org/ was used to validate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you used the validator's DOCTYPE setting to use the HTML5, since you did not include one in the source.

The `<content>` tag has been [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/content) from HTML.

You should use an alternative HTML tag, like a `<section>` or `<article>` tag if you want to use HTML5 tags, or a plain old `<div>` if that's not what you're going for.